# REST URI design: how update

Tags: web-services, rest, http, uri

I have a design question of REST URI.

Suppose i have a Car resource (that is mapped in the database with some properties). 
If i want update the Car resource with the information of another Car i know that i can call

```
PUT /base_url/api/cars/1

I update the car with id == 1 with the informations in the request body
```

But if i want update the car with id == 1 with the information of the car with id == 2? (i'd like to pass only id because the copy is handled internally by the server)
How can i design this type of request in rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use PATCH instead.

> The difference between the PUT and PATCH requests is reflected in
> the    way the server processes the enclosed entity to modify the
> resource    identified by the Request-URI.  In a PUT request, the
> enclosed entity    is considered to be a modified version of the
> resource stored on the    origin server, and the client is requesting
> that the stored version    be replaced.  With PATCH, however, the
> enclosed entity contains a set    of instructions describing how a
> resource currently residing on the    origin server should be modified
> to produce a new version.  The PATCH    method affects the resource
> identified by the Request-URI, and it    also MAY have side effects on
> other resources; i.e., new resources    may be created, or existing
> ones modified, by the application of a    PATCH.

- [PATCH Method for HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789)

Something like this would be okay:

```
PATCH /base_url/api/cars/1 
{template: {id: 2}}
```

Don't send the id in the query, because it is part of the URI, which is the identifier of your target resource.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a PUT request to this URI: PUT **/base_url/api/cars/1?clone=2**, and pass information (in JSON body).

In the backend I would find the data for car #2, and merge it with the data I got from the request.

This way you could clone the resource, and modify its attributes at the same time.